# How to close the widgte by dragging it down

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wish Widget could close in two ways, the way below and drag Widget down.

````
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new ... (...),
          floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: ()=> exit(0),
            tooltip: 'Close app',
            child: new Icon(Icons.close),
          ), 
    );
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Draggable widget for drag down dismissal.https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html